# cmd.exe batch to crop dirname

Tags: batch-file, cmd, rename

I have a directory structure that reads like:

```
nnnnnn~substring
```

Where `n` are numbers, and `substring` are letters.
I am trying to write a batch file that tests if a particular file exists inside the directory, and if it does, it should rename the directory to substring.
The batch file should look like:

```
for /f "tokens=\*" %%a in ('dir /b') do if exist filename (rename nnnnnn~substring substring)
```

How do I trim all the numbers and the ~ character of the directory name so I can rename it using only the final part of the name?
The numbers before the ~ separator have different lengths, so does the substring after it.

Comment: Edit the question and specify what is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    rem Change to the target folder 
    pushd "x:\somewhere" && (

        rem For each folder inside it matching the indicated pattern
        rem     Uses a dir command to search only folders and a 
        rem     findstr filter to ensure only matching folders 
        for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
            dir /ad /b *~* ^| findstr /r /c:"^[0-9][0-9]*~..*$"
        ') do (

            rem Check if the folder contains the file
            if exist "%%~fa\flagFile.txt" (

                rem Split the folder name using the ~ as delimiter
                for /f "tokens=1,* delims=~" %%b in ("%%~na") do (

                    rem Check that the new folder name does not exist
                    if not exist "%%~c%%~xa" (
                        rem Execute the rename operation
                        echo ren "%%~fa" "%%~c%%~xa"
                    )
                )
            )
        )
        rem Restore previous active directory
        popd
    )
```

Rename operations are only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` that prefixes `ren` command

Answer (score 0):

This may work - test it in a copy of your folder structure:
It assumes that `substring` in your question does not contain any `~` characters.

```
@echo off
:loop
for /d /r "d:\base\folder" %%a in (*~*) do (
  if exist "%%a\filename" for /f "tokens=1,* delims=~" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do (
    ren "%%a" "%%c"
    goto :loop 
  )
)
pause
```

This is designed for only the folders within the current directory.

```
@echo off
for /d %%a in (*~*) do (
  if exist "%%a\filename" for /f "tokens=1,* delims=~" %%b in ("%%~nxa") do ren "%%a" "%%c"
)
pause
```

Comment: This can be simplified if your folder structure does not include nested subdirectories.

Comment: It does the job, but then loops repeating the error "File already exists or file not found" and I have to stop it with Ctrl-C. BTW: There aren't nested directories.

Comment: @Ignasi What name did you use for the batch file?  Are all `substring` sections unique?